# Solr 4.6: Delete a word from a field using PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm trying to delete a word "SomeWord" from a text field using solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory.  I'm using "copyField" to copy "title" into "title_filt" and it doesn't look like my pattern is matching.  I've even tried to use a pattern of ".*" to match anything and it has no effect.  The config from my schema is below:

```
<fieldType name="text_char_filter" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
     <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="SomeWord" replacement="TEST"/>
     <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="title_filt" type="text_char_filter" stored="true" indexed="true"/>  

<copyField source="title" dest="title_filt"/>
```

Any help getting this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you are better off using a stopFilter. This discards words and not characters. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.StopFilterFactory

Comment: Yes; if I search using "title_filt:SomeWord" I get thousands of results.  I also see that the field has "SomeWord" in it when I look at the XML returned by the query.  Okke: stopFilter might work for me, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Is the same filter being applied to the query as well?  That would explain why you are getting hits on it, since `SomeWord` would have been transformed into `TEST` both in the index and in the query.  The fact that the word still appears in the XML is expected.  The analyzer only affects the indexed version of the text, not the stored version.  It's there to facilitate search, not to transform the stored document text.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not supposed to transform the stored text?  The description of char filters on the solr wiki seems to imply that it should: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Char_Filters